# JMeter - saving properties in variables, but JMeter not resolving the variable

Tags: csv, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, properties-file, jsr223

I'm using the JMeter Property file reader successfully to get values from a file.

Then I use a simple Groovy snippet to save those values in variables.

Why, then, is JMeter still thinking the variable is not defined?

Output to the console shows that the variables are being stored.

```
for (i in props)    
    if (i.key.startsWith('testData')) {
        vars.put(i.key, i.value)
        log.info(vars.get(i.key))
    }
```

tigapo.prop:

```
testData.getUserHistoryPageUsingGETFile=HistoryControllerApi.csv
testData.createBillingUsingPOSTFile=BillingControllerApi.csv
testData.getCreditExchangeInfoUsingGETFile=BillingControllerApi.csv
testData.handleTagDetectionUsingPOSTFile=TagDetectionControllerApi.csv
testData.getSettingsUsingGETFile=SettingsControllerApi.csv
testData.createUserUsingPOSTFile=UserControllerApi.csv
```

[image]

With all steps disabled except one, no errors, and I get the vars in the output.

[image]

When I enable one step that uses a variable, the error is displayed.

[image]

And here is the CSV Data Config:
[image]

---

To make my comment easier to read:
Did what was suggested.
[image]

And verified that:
[image]

But still getting:

```
2022-05-10 16:32:46,656 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: ${testData.getUserUsingGETFile} Alias: ${testData.getUserUsingGETFile}@11286416
2022-05-10 16:32:46,656 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not read file header line for file ${testData.getUserUsingGETFile}
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.reserveFile(FileServer.java:283) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet.initVars(CSVDataSet.java:208) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet.iterationStart(CSVDataSet.java:171) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:399) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:391) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:160) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:134) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:91) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_311]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File ${testData.getUserUsingGETFile} must exist and be readable
```

```
testData.getUserUsingGETFile=UserControllerApi.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because CSV Data Set Config is being initialized **before** JSR223 PreProcessor, take a look at JMeter test elements [execution order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder):

```
0. Configuration elements
1. Pre-Processors
2. Timers
3. Sampler
4. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
5. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
6. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)
```

CSV Data Set Config is a [configuration element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) hence it's being run before anything else.

so you need to:

1. Convert JSR223 PreProcessor to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
2. Put it under [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test)

Comment: Hi - I tried this: put JSR223 sampler under setUp Thread Group, verified via Debug PostProcessor that variables were saved, and still getting "2022-05-10 16:32:46,656 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: ${testData.getUserUsingGETFile} Alias: ${testData.getUserUsingGETFile}@11286416
2022-05-10 16:32:46,656 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not read file header line for file ${testData.getUserUsingGETFile}
"

Comment: [JMeter properties are not the same as variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), if you're setting the property via groovy my expectation is that you need to be getting it via groovy as well, i.e. instead of your `${testData.getUserUsingGETFile}` you need to use `${__groovy(props.get('testData.getUserHistoryPageUsingGETFile'),)}`. See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details.

Comment: That groovy script is setting variables, not properties, which I verified by doing `log.info(vars.get(i.key))`.         For that matter, I already know I can use `${__P('testData.getUserHistoryPageUsingGETFile',)}` successfully.  I was just trying to avoid editing several steps that I copied from elsewhere.

Comment: If you only bothered to open the [link](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) I provided you would learn that variables are [local to the thread](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter#comment-5853352937) so they cannot be accessed outside the thread where they're set. That's why you need to use properties or go for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter) when you need to share data between threads in the same or different thread groups.